# Unable to find PixelFormat Enum for Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, xamarin.android, image-reader

I have the below code where i am creating a ImageReader instance in xamarin android, how to change Image Format from `ImageFormatType.Rgb565` to `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888`

i am unable to find the Library or a Enum class for it.

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(windowWidth, windowHeight, ImageFormatType.Rgb565, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an int value of `3` (`Android.Graphics.Format.Rgb888`) to `ImageReader.NewInstance`, but currently you can not.

That is a bug/issue in Xamarin.Android auto-generation API process as they do not create a overload that accepts an `Android.Graphics.Format` enum, or just a plain `int` as the Java API does.

You can do this the same way you would do it in Java via Xamarin.Android's binding to Android.Runtime.JNIEnv or Java.Lang.Reflect

#### Example using JNI:

Note: Using JNI requires that the assembly be allowed to use "unsafe" code ( on the plus side, JNI is faster execution than using reflection...)

```
public static class ImageReaderEx
{
    public unsafe static ImageReader NewInstance(int width, int height, Android.Graphics.Format format, int maxImages)
    {
        JniArgumentValue* ptr = stackalloc JniArgumentValue[4];
        *ptr = new JniArgumentValue(width);
        ptr[1] = new JniArgumentValue(height);
        ptr[2] = new JniArgumentValue((int)format);
        ptr[3] = new JniArgumentValue(maxImages);
        JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers("android/media/ImageReader", typeof(ImageReader));
        return Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<ImageReader>(_members.StaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod("newInstance.(IIII)Landroid/media/ImageReader;", ptr).Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
    }

    public unsafe static ImageReader NewInstance(int width, int height, int format, int maxImages)
    {
        JniArgumentValue* ptr = stackalloc JniArgumentValue[4];
        *ptr = new JniArgumentValue(width);
        ptr[1] = new JniArgumentValue(height);
        ptr[2] = new JniArgumentValue(format);
        ptr[3] = new JniArgumentValue(maxImages);
        JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers("android/media/ImageReader", typeof(ImageReader));
        return Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<ImageReader>(_members.StaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod("newInstance.(IIII)Landroid/media/ImageReader;", ptr).Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
var imageReader = ImageReaderEx.NewInstance(1, 1, 3, 1);
```

or

```
var ImageReader = ImageReaderEx.NewInstance(1, 1, Android.Graphics.Format.Rgb888, 1);
```

Comment: which jar file I should use for binding? and where to find them?

Comment: No jar file needed.

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS No jar file, just via Java reflection or JNI, if you do not know how, I can help you with code later (not at my PC)

Comment: can u show me how, because I cannot understand it, I am new to this, i will wait for the code.

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS I added an example

Comment: Ok, i will check it now :)

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS That does not have anything to do with this question/answer, you need to post a new question with that code.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, its `Format.Rgba8888` (lower case). the doc is [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Format/)

Comment: That will not work as ImageReader.NewInstance does not accept a `Format` enum  as a parameter, it is an issue in the auto-generated API bindings...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495618/3154381):

```
var imageReader = ImageReader.NewInstance(_mWidth, _mHeight, (ImageFormatType)Format.Rgba8888, 2);
```

It's working for me.